# Library cannot resolve R. symbol

Tags: java, android, gradle

I try to add external library "**ViewPagerIndicator**".

I add `build.gradle` to library and compile it.
There is a few classes in library that cannot import support library, but I have it in `build.gradle` of my app

```
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
```

It gives me `Error:(28, 31) error: package android.support.v4.view does not exist`. Library cannot resolve  `R.`symbol.

Then I try to add support library within ViewPagerIndicator library

Here is the `Application/ViewPagerIndicator/build.gradle`

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  //Tells the build this is a library project

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'  //Where to find specific parts of the project
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
```

And it gives me `Gradle DSL method not found 'compile()'` error.

Please, say how to fix it

**UPDATE**

I put `dependencies` below `android`.

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'  //Tells the build this is a library project

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'  //Where to find specific parts of the project
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
configurations {
    // Used for correct javadoc generation
    javadoc.extendsFrom compile
}
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

And it worked, but not at all

Library still cannot resolve `R.` symbol